# When modifying $_ can be wrong?

Tags: perl

**When the following code could have side effects?**

```
@some = map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;
```

The perlcritic explains it as dangerous, because for example:

```
@other = map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;
```

and the members of the `@some` got **also** modified. Understand. I have the BPB book, and it shows the above with the example

```
@pm_files_without_pl_files
         = grep { s/.pm\z/.pl/xms && !-e } @pm_files;
```

and also I read the chapter "*List Processing Side Effects*" / "*Never modify $_ in a list function*." and its followers. Also i know the `/r`.

To be clear (as much is possible with my terrible english):

In the 1st example the main point is modifying the original `@some`.

The question is about:

- **could the 1st example** `@some = map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;` **causing some unwanted side-effects**? If yes, when?
- or it is just the "not recommented" way (but **harmless** otherwise)?

Looking for an answer what goes a bit deeper as some "perl beginner's book" - therefore still doesn't accepted any current answer. ;)

Comment: Try adding non-destructive `r` modifier: `map { s/xxx/y/r }` Available from Perl 5.13.2, see http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/12/perl-5-14-adds-non-destructive-transliteration/

Comment: The background for critic is described in chapter 5 of the [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do)

Comment: @HåkonHægland - i have the book, and also read it... edited the question to be (i hope) more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the mottos of perl has always been TIMTOWTDI: there is more than one way to do it. If two ways have the same end result, they're equally correct. That doesn't mean there aren't reasons to prefer one way over the other.

In the first case, it would be more obvious (to me, YMMV) to do something like

```
s/xxx/y/ for @some;
```

This is mainly because it's communicating intend better. `for` suggests it's all about the side effect, whereas `map` suggests it's about the return value. While functionally identical, this should be much easier to understand for your fellow programmer (and probably for yourself in 6 months from now).

There's more than one way, but some are better than others.

Answer (score 7):

Code like your example:

```perl
@some = map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;
```

should be avoided because it's redundant and confusing.  It *looks like* the assignment on the left should be doing something, even though it's actually a no-op.  Indeed, just writing:

```perl
map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;
```

would have the exact same effect, as would:

```perl
map { s/xxx/y/ } @some;
```

This version at least has the virtue of making it (reasonably) clear that the return value of `map` is being ignored, and that the actual purpose of the statement is to modify `@some` in place.

But of course, as Leon has already pointed out, by far the clearest and most idiomatic way of writing this would be:

```perl
s/xxx/y/ for @some;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@some = map { s/xxx/y/; $_ } @some;
```

will work fine, but it's very poor code because it's not obvious that you're effectively doing

```
map { s/xxx/y/ } @some; @some = @some;
```

This already shows you could simply have done

```
map { s/xxx/y/ } @some;
```

But that's a misleading and inefficient version of

```
s/xxx/y/ for @some;
```

It's all about readability and maintainability.

---

Note that you can do

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );

@some = apply { s/xxx/y/ } @some;
```

And in Perl 5.14+,

```
@some = map { s/xxx/y/r } @some;
```